# How to get URLencoded data from the body of a POST in CGI Perl

Tags: perl, cgi, mime-types

POSTDATA is not the correct answer.  I have read the docs and still don't see how I can get the data.

I want to receive this request:

```
POST /cgi-bin/myscript.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Length: 3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

255
```

and have the server respond
You sent the string "255"

Please assist, I am a Perl beginner and have gotten a bunch of seemingly wrong and useless answers to this seemingly simple request.

Comment: have you checked the `CGI` documentation?

Comment: That's a malformed request. The data is not in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: How is it malformed? alphanumeric characters appear as themselves, non alphanumerics are hex representations of their ascii code, right?  Is it malformed because it isnt a pair like param=value?

Comment: Yes, I looked at some CGI docs as I stated right in my question, , but there is a point where it becomes counterproductive.  I couldn't find an answer for this, only the POSTDATA param which applies to non urlencoded content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI will automatically parse form data, so you need to hide that what you got is form data (or at least claims to be).

```
use CGI qw( );
$ENV{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/octet-stream';
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $post_data = $cgi->param('POSTDATA');
```

Better solution: Have the requester use a correct content type (e.g. `application/octet-stream`), or have the requester actually send form data (e.g. `data=255`).

Answer (score 0):

Unique solution for me, was change of ContentType on client's petition to 'application/octet-stream'

Module CGI CPAN says:

> If POSTed data is not of type **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** or
>   **multipart/form-data**, then the POSTed data will not be processed, but
>   instead be returned as-is in a parameter named POSTDATA.

So if you can't change on clients petition to other ContentType, it won't be processed.

Answer (score -1):

CGI (in recent versions at least) will stuff incorrectly encoded `x-www-form-urlencoded` params into a parameter named `keywords`. Better to send a proper content type though, then the POSTDATA works exactly as the docs say:

> If POSTed data is not of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded or
>   multipart/form-data, then the POSTed data will not be processed...

```
use strictures;
use CGI::Emulate::PSGI;
use Plack::Test;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Test::More;

my $post = POST "/non-e-importa",
    "Content-Length" => 5,
    "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Content => "ohai\n";

my $cgis = CGI::Emulate::PSGI->handler( sub {
    use CGI "param", "header";
    my $incorrectly_encoded_body = param("keywords");
    print header("text/plain"), $incorrectly_encoded_body;
});

test_psgi $cgis, sub {
    my $cb  = shift;
    my $res = $cb->($post);
    is $res->content, "ohai", "Soopersek437 param: keywords";
};

done_testing();

__END__
prove so-16846138 -v
ok 1 - Soopersek437 param: keywords
1..1
ok
All tests successful.
Result: PASS
```

Comment: Fails for `"abc=def"` and `"abc\ndef"`, and possibly fails for `"61%61"`.

Comment: @ikegami, of course. Since the input is wrong™ handling the OP’s spec is as fragile as the expectations. Without decoding routines or actual content type comparisons, fallbacks your answer has plenty of fail cases unrelated to the OP too. :P

Comment: What are you saying, `255` is the only thing he'll receive? Then why not just suggest `my $post_data = '255';`? Your code does not return the request body as requested.